# Responsive Navigation without duplicate links?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Recently I've been attempting to make my own responsive navigation and have managed to, but now i'm wanting to jump the next hurdle, which is to create the same navigation but without having two seperate link lists.

Now I've tried various methods to get this to work, including using javascript to add / remove classes when at a certain width, which worked to a certain extent, but only if i resized the browser for it to find out the browser width, which obviously has it's flaws when you can't resize the browser when on a mobile device.

The code i've currently got is -

HTML

```
<nav class="mainnav" role="navigation">
    <div class="desktopnav" id="navigation">
            <ul class="mainlinks">
                <li role="menuitem"><a href="#top-page">Home</a></li>
                <li role="menuitem"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li role="menuitem"><a href="#mywork">My Work</a></li>
                <li role="menuitem"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mobilenav">
        <button class="navtoggle">toggle</button>
            <ul class="mainlinks">
                <li role="menuitem"><a href="#top-page">Home</a></li>
                <li role="menuitem"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li role="menuitem"><a href="#mywork">My Work</a></li>
                <li role="menuitem"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.mainnav {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #64137B; }

/*Desktop nav*/
.desktopnav {
  display: block; }

.desktopnav ul.mainlinks {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: table;
  min-height: 50px; }

.desktopnav ul.mainlinks li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #A37EAE; }

.desktopnav ul.mainlinks li:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #A37EAE; }

.desktopnav ul.mainlinks a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none; }

.mobilenav, .desktopnav {
  min-height: 50px;
  height: auto; }

/*Mobile Nav*/
.mobilenav {
  text-align: center; }

.mobilenav, button.navtoggle {
  display: none; }

.mobilenav ul.mainlinks {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0px; }

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .desktopnav {
    display: none; }

  .mobilenav {
    display: block; }

  button.navtoggle {
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 5px auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0;
    text-indent: 200%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white url(../../images/navbutton.png) center no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-size: 80%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out; }

  button.navtoggle:hover {
    opacity: 0.7; }

  ul.mainlinks {
    background: #8421A0;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px; }

  ul.mainlinks li {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #A37EAE; }

  ul.mainlinks a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none; } 
}
```

Has anyone got any ideas on what i might be able to do, to fix my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [media queries](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/), that way you can set position values entirely based on the size of the screen:

```
.nav {
  /* some common properties here */

  /* some positioning properties here */
  /* these will be set for everything and may need over-riding */
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .nav {
    /* some completely different positioning properties here */
    /* remember, some may be over-rides */
  }
}
```

Declaring the common properties in a class then over-riding as the screen gets wider is basic mobile first best practice - it enables you to handle tough layout issues with room to expand, rather than getting everything perfect large and finding it's hard to squeeze down. In some cases, you may need to use a declaration like this:

```
@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  /* properties */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I do know how to use media queries, I've just hit a blank with how to apply them in the way I know. I think I'll take a break from it tonight then start afresh with sorting them into different media queries.

Comment: @MoMartin yes, I see now, I missed some of the code in the question, I blame invisible Mac scrollbars lol, try removing everything and just working with basic positioned boxes and getting them in the correct place with one HTML element before adding in the extra fluff - you should be looking at properties like `position`